# lazy evaluation implementation will not compile

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation, pointer-to-member

The following code has a promise class, which takes a class, function from this class and an input, and which it evaluates into a result var when asked to do so. There is a vector class which can be initialized with a promise and a promise test class which for the purpose of this question just realizes the promise to resize a vector variable.

In the main I create two `promise` test variables: one for vector int and the other for vector double. The problem is that the code will not compile as given below (with g++ SUSE Linux 4.3.4 revision 152973) but compiles and runs fine if I remove `t1` and `v1`. The compilation error I get says that the compiler cannot see the template promise constructor for the vector double variable.

Any ideas what might be happening? Its like the first instantiation of the test/vector pair shadows the second.

```c++
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                   
#include <vector>                                                                                                                         

using namespace std;

#define FUNC(O, I, R, F) void(O::*F)(const I&, R&) const
template<typename O, typename I, typename R, FUNC(O, I, R, F)>
struct promise
{
    promise(const O& _o, const I& _x) : o(_o), x(_x)
    { }

    inline void eval_into(R& r) const
    {
        (o.*(F))(x, r);
    }

    const O& o;
    const I& x;
};

template<typename T>
struct vec: public vector<T>
{
    typedef vector<T> base;
    vec(const vec& v) : base(v)
    { }

    vec() : base()
    { }

    template<typename O, typename I, FUNC(O, I, vec, F)>
    vec(const promise<O, I, vec, F>& p)
    {
        p.eval_into(*this);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct promise_test
{
    typedef vec<T> vect;
    inline void eval_f(const int& s, vect& r) const
    {
        r.resize(s);
    }

    typedef promise<promise_test, int, vect, &promise_test::eval_f> promise_type;

    inline promise_type f(const int& s) const
    {
        return promise_type(*this, s);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x = 5;

    promise_test<int> t1;
    vec<int> v1(t1.f(x));

    promise_test<double> t2;
    vec<double> v2(t2.f(x));

    cout << v2.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wait -- g++3.4.3? It works fine with g++4.8.2 and clang++3.4

Comment: sorry 4.3.4 :-) But it might be a bug in my compiler... In fact I suspect as much but will wait to see if someone else picks up before giving you the answer.